# Problems with backgrounds in input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, checkbox, textinput

When I double click the card the dialog pops up, and it is then possible to create checkBoxes. So far so good. Then I want to if I create one checkBox in the dialog and save the data via button, the value of created checkBoxes appears on the card. Then if all checkBoxes who are created is checked, a green background appears on the card. To indicate that the task got finish. like in the image below:

[image]

When I do create two cards, and one of them indicate the task got finish, like in the image above. In the second one you just create eg. two checkBoxes. Then the issue is, that the green background disperses from the first card. like in the Image below:

[image: Image2]

The code in JQuery:

```
function CheckBoxesChecked() {
        var numAll = $('input[type="checkbox"]').length;
        var numChecked = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;

        if (numChecked == numAll) {

            $('.checkBoxCard').css("background-image", "none").addClass('jo');
        }
        else {
            $('.checkBoxCard').removeClass('jo').css('background-image', "url('/Pages/Images/creampaper.png')");
        }
    }
```

I tried to fix it by the code below:

```
function CheckBoxesChecked() {
        var numAll = $('input[type="checkbox"]').length;
        var numChecked = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;

        if (numChecked == numAll) {

            $currentTarget.$('.checkBoxCard').css("background-image", "none").addClass('jo');
        }
        else {
            $currentTarget.$('.checkBoxCard').removeClass('jo').css('background-image', "url('/Pages/Images/creampaper.png')");
        }
    }
```

Where I use $currentTarget to indicate that each card is unique. But it seems not working. Any idea how to fix the issue?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dhuKS/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
$currentTarget.$('.checkBoxCard').css("background-image", "none").addClass('jo');
```

to

```
$currentTarget.find('.checkBoxCard').css("background-image", "none").addClass('jo');
```

See the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhuKS/1/).

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly that what I was looking for. But I don't understand why to use find? What is the difference?

Comment: You use [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to find jQuery objects which are descendants of another jQuery object. The first jQuery object (`$currentTarget`) does not have a method `$()`.

Answer (score 0):

use e.delegateTarget instead of target. see https://api.jquery.com/event.delegateTarget/